# unable to run hive jobs in parallel

Tags: hadoop, parallel-processing, hive

I need to run multiple independent insert statements to put data into a HIVE table in parallel. The individual commands are like:

```
hive -e "insert into fieldcounts select 'fname', count(*) from tab1 where fname is not null"
```

I have 100 fields, so I generated a 100 insert statements. HIVE would run each insert as its own map reduce job. I would like to be able to run 10-20 of these insert statements in parallel to speed up the process.

However I was unable to achieve that using xargs or gnu-parallel or even manually creating a shell script with multiple hive -e commmands running in background. I notice that hive instances always run sequentially.

It is as if a single execution of a hive command blocks all other hive commands. The commands will run sequentially not matter what I try.

Has anyone else faced this? What are my alternatives? Can I force a single HIVE map reduce to achieve what I am trying? Is there a way to force multiple hive commands to actually execute in parallel?

> EDIT:

Thank you Stephen for pointing out the locks. So I will modify the question. Is there a mechanism for me to tell hive not to exclusively lock the target table of my insert statement, so I can do multiple inserts in parallel? Preferably I would like to make the determination when making the INSERT and not diable locks globally.

Comment: Are you running on a cluster or a pseudo distributed VM? When you kick off a few inserts, enter the Hive CLI and run the command 'show locks' and 'show locks extended' - does it show you any locks held on the table?

Comment: You are correct @StephenODonnell. There was an exclusive lock placed on the table where I was inserting, blocking all other calls! Silly me!

Comment: I haven't tested this myself, but the docs here https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Locking#Locking-TurnOffConcurrency suggest that setting hive.support.concurrency=false disables the locks. You would need to test if that works and also what happens to concurrent inserts. You could try just setting this in your inserts and not globally to see if it works.